# How to create a map with custom class/comparator as key

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, comparator, stdmap

I have a class named `ItemType`. It has two members - both double, named `m_t` and `m_f`. Two items of type `ItemType` are considered to be equal if these two members differ from each other within respective tolerance levels. With this logic, the comparator function is so defined as well. However, when I insert objects of this type as key into a map, only one key is produced in the map, even though at least three such keys should be present:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>  
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

        class ItemKey
        {
        public:
            ItemKey(double t, double f)
            {
                m_t = t;
                m_f = f;           
            }

            double m_t;
            double m_f;
            double m_tEpsilon = 3;
            double m_fEpsilon = 0.1;

            bool operator<(const ItemKey& itemKey) const
            {
                int s_cmp = (abs(itemKey.m_f - m_f) > m_fEpsilon);
                if (s_cmp == 0)
                {
                    return (abs(itemKey.m_t - m_t) > m_tEpsilon);
                }
                return s_cmp < 0;
            }
        };

int main()
{
    // The pairs are the respective values of m_t and m_f.
    vector<pair<double, double>> pairs;

    // These two should belong in one bucket -> (109.9, 9.0), because m_f differs by 0.09 and m_t differs by just 1
    pairs.emplace_back(109.9, 9.0);
    pairs.emplace_back(110.9, 9.09);

    // This one is separate from above two beause even though m_t is in range, m_f is beyong tolerance level
    pairs.emplace_back(109.5, 10.0);

    // Same for this as well, here both m_t and m_f are beyong tolerance of any of the two categories found above
    pairs.emplace_back(119.9, 19.0);

    // This one matches the second bucket - (109.5, 10.0)
    pairs.emplace_back(109.9, 10.05);

    // And this one too.
    pairs.emplace_back(111.9, 9.87);

    map<ItemKey, size_t> itemMap;

    for (const auto& item: pairs)
    {
        ItemKey key(item.first, item.second);
        auto iter = itemMap.find(key);
        if (iter  == itemMap.end())
        {
            itemMap[key] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            itemMap[iter->first] = itemMap[iter->first] + 1;
        }
    }

    // The map should have three keys - (109.9, 9.0) -> count 2, (109.5, 10.0) -> count 3 and (119.9, 19.0) -> count 1
    cout << itemMap.size();

}
```

However, the map seems to have only 1 key. How do I make it work as expected?

Comment: If it returns false for both a<b and b<a, it will deem them identical. Is it the case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What I want is this - for two items **a** and **b**, if the respective member variables **m_f** and **m_t** are within tolerance levels of each other, the map should treat both items as same key, and keep the first inserted key in the map, and on getting the second key for insertion, instead of inserting it, should just increment the count of the value for the existing key.

Comment: @SexyBeast `int s_cmp = (abs(itemKey.m_f - m_f) > m_fEpsilon);` -- That yields a value of `true` or `false`.  Assigning to an `int` just convolutes the code.  In addition, you compute this twice, thus risking (maybe in rare cases), a different result on the second computation.

Comment: Also `return s_cmp < 0;` now makes very little sense, since `s_cmp` was assigned either `true` or `false` converted to an integer.

Comment: I tried changing the comparator function to one line - `return (abs(itemKey.m_f - m_f) <= m_fEpsilon) && (abs(itemKey.m_t - m_t) <= m_tEpsilon);`, that now yields the size as 10. Weird!

Comment: Your comparisons just do not follow a strict-weak-order.  You're supposed to return `true` for arguments (a,b) if `a < b`.  However your function also returns true if the arguments are (b,a), where you're saying `b < a`.  That violates the strict-weak-order.

Comment: Okay, how do I make it strictly weak then??

Comment: Here is the issue -- Your `<` function is given two item keys, the `this` and the argument passed in.  You return `true` for those arguments.  Then let's say a smart runtime tries to detect your failure by passing the argument first, and then `this`.  You return `true` for that also.  How can that be, where you say one is true, and the other is true using the same arguments, only switched?  How to solve it?  You have to devise a scheme where the scenario I pointed out will not play itself out.

Comment: Okay, that explains it pretty well, thanks! Except I am at a loss on how to devise the solution as you said..

Comment: @SexyBeast --  *I am at a loss on how to devise the solution* -- Well I guess that's your homework assignment for today :).  Defining order unambiguously may take a little bit more sophistication, but it can be done.

Comment: @SexyBeast *ItemType are considered to be equal* -- Maybe that's where the disconnect occurs.  That states what makes two `ItemType`'s equal -- it does not state what makes one `ItemType` less than another `ItemType`, and again, unambiguously so.  You need to be told the rules of `<` and write code according to that rule.

Comment: Well, if you want to works with floating points, you have to ensure that your numbers are rounded to desired precision (for ex. 1/128) early and that once you have such number, you don't do any operations on them. And you also have to ensure that your range is not too big so that every number in your range can be rounded to the desired precision. Also, you have to ensure you don't have INF and NAN or explicitly define their ordering (but then it will slow down searching items). Alternatively, you could use long integers that scale data as desired.

Comment: To have **strict weak ordering**, you must forget about epsilon. And if you don't do it, you have **undefined behavior** which in practice means that it is always possible to have a case where the code does not behave as expected. Really, you should either normalize data to a given precision or make appropriate adjustment to your code when inserting data. In any case the set or multiset should be hidden from client code so that you could do appropriate logic when inserting or searching data. If you want to group data at each 0.1, then I would probably round data to 1/16 if using floats.

Comment: **Strick weak ordering**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why isn't your version working?

You did well to create your own comparison function.  To answer your question, you have an error in your `operator<()` function such that only returns true if `m_f` is outside of tolerance and `m_t` is within tolerance, which I'm guessing is not what you desired.  Let's take a look.

```
int s_cmp = (abs(itemKey.m_f - m_f) > m_fEpsilon);
```

The above line basically is checking whether `this->m_f` and `itemKey.m_f` are within tolerance of eachother (meaning equal to each other).  That is probably what was intended.  Then you say

```
if (s_cmp == 0)
{
    return (abs(itemKey.m_t - m_t) > m_tEpsilon);
}
```

If `s_cmp` is `true`, then it will have the value of `1`, and it will have a value of `0` for `false` (meaning that they are *not* within tolerance of each other).  Then you return true if the `m_t` value is within tolerance.  Up to this point, you return `true` if `m_f` is *not* equal (according to tolerance) and if `m_t` *is* equal (according to tolerance).  Then your last line of code

```
return s_cmp < 0;
```

will return `true` always since a boolean converted to an integer cannot ever be negative.

## How to get it working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>  
#include <vector>

struct ItemKey
{
    double m_t;
    double m_f;
    static constexpr double t_eps = 3;
    static constexpr double f_eps = 0.1;

    ItemKey(double t, double f) : m_t(t), m_f(f) {}

    bool operator<(const ItemKey& other) const
    {
        // Here it is assumed that f_eps and t_eps are positive
        // We also ignore overflow, underflow, and NaN
        // This is written for readability, and assumed the compiler will be
        // able to optimize it.
        auto fuzzy_less_than = [] (double a, double b, double eps) {
          return a < b - eps;
        };
        bool f_is_less_than    = fuzzy_less_than(this->m_f, other.m_f, f_eps);
        bool f_is_greater_than = fuzzy_less_than(other.m_f, this->m_f, f_eps);
        bool f_is_equal        = !f_is_less_than && !f_is_greater_than;
        bool t_is_less_than    = fuzzy_less_than(this->m_t, other.m_t, t_eps);

        return f_is_less_than || (f_is_equal && t_is_less_than);
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    // The pairs are the respective values of m_t and m_f.
    vector<pair<double, double>> pairs;

    // These two should belong in one bucket
    // -> (109.9, 9.0), because m_f differs by 0.09 and m_t differs by just 1
    pairs.emplace_back(109.9, 9.0);
    pairs.emplace_back(110.9, 9.09);

    // This one is separate from above two beause even though m_t is in range,
    // m_f is beyong tolerance level
    pairs.emplace_back(109.5, 10.0);

    // Same for this as well, here both m_t and m_f are beyong tolerance of any
    // of the two categories found above
    pairs.emplace_back(119.9, 19.0);

    // This one matches the second bucket - (109.5, 10.0)
    pairs.emplace_back(109.9, 10.05);

    // And this one too.
    pairs.emplace_back(111.9, 9.87);

    map<ItemKey, size_t> itemMap;

    for (const auto& item: pairs)
    {
        ItemKey key(item.first, item.second);
        auto iter = itemMap.find(key);
        if (iter  == itemMap.end())
        {
            itemMap[key] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            itemMap[iter->first] = itemMap[iter->first] + 1;
        }
    }

    // The map should have three keys
    // - (109.9, 9.0) -> count 2
    // - (109.5, 10.0) -> count 3
    // - (119.9, 19.0) -> count 1
    cout << itemMap.size();

    cout << "itemMap contents:" << endl;
    for (auto& item : itemMap) {
        cout << "  (" << item.first << ", " << ")" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are a few things I changed above.  I have a few suggestions also unrelated to the programming mistake:

1. Do not store boolean values into integer variables.
   There's a reason that C++ introduced the `bool` type.
2. Write your code to be readable *and* in a way that the compiler
   can easily optimize.  You may notice I used a lambda expression
   and multiple booleans.  Smart compilers will inline the calls to
   that lambda expression since it is only used within the local scope.
   Also smart compilers can simplify boolean logic and make it
   performant for me.
3. The `m_tEpsilon` and `m_fEpsilon` are probably not good to be
   changable variables of the class.  In fact, it may be bad if one
   object has a different epsilon than another one.  If that were the
   case, which do you use when you do the `<` operator?  For this
   reason, I set them as `static const` variables in the class.
4. For constructors, it is better to initialize your variables in the
   initializer list rather than in the body of the constructor.  That
   is unless you are doing dynamic resource allocation, then you would
   want to do it in the constructor and make sure to clean it up if
   you end up throwing an exception (preferrably using the RAII
   pattern).  I'm starting to get too far off topic :)
5. Even though `class` and `struct` are basically identical except for
   the default protection level (`class` is private by default and
   `struct` is public by default).  It is convention to have it as a
   struct if you want direct access to the member variables.  Although,
   in this case, I would probably set your class as immutable.  To do
   that, set the `m_t` and `m_f` as private variables and have a getter
   `m()` and `f()`.  It might be a bad idea to modify an `ItemKey`
   instance in a map after it has been inserted.

## Potential problems with this approach

One of the problems you have with your approach here is that it will be dependent on the order in which you add elements.  Consider the following pairs to be added: `(3.0, 10.0) (5.0, 10.0) (7.0, 10.0)`.  If we add them in that order, we will get `(3.0, 10.0) (7.0, 10.0)`, since `(5.0, 10.0)` was deemed to be equal to `(3.0, 10.0)`.  But what if we were to have inserted `(5.0, 10.0)` first, then the other two?  Well then the list would only have one element, `(5.0, 10.0)`, since bother of the others would be considered equal to this one.

Instead, I would like to suggest that you use `std::multiset` instead, of course this will depend on your application.  Consider these tests:

```
void simple_test_map() {
    std::map<ItemKey, size_t> counter1;
    counter1[{3.0, 10.0}] += 1;
    counter1[{5.0, 10.0}] += 1;
    counter1[{7.0, 10.0}] += 1;
    for (auto &itempair : counter1) {
       std::cout << "simple_test_map()::counter1: ("
                 << itempair.first.m_t << ", "
                 << itempair.first.m_f << ") - "
                 << itempair.second << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::map<ItemKey, size_t> counter2;
    counter2[{5.0, 10.0}] += 1;
    counter2[{3.0, 10.0}] += 1;
    counter2[{7.0, 10.0}] += 1;
    for (auto &itempair : counter2) {
       std::cout << "simple_test_map()::counter2: ("
                 << itempair.first.m_t << ", "
                 << itempair.first.m_f << ") - "
                 << itempair.second << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs:

```
simple_test_map()::counter1: (3, 10) - 2
simple_test_map()::counter1: (7, 10) - 1

simple_test_map()::counter2: (5, 10) - 3
```

And for the multiset variant:

```
void simple_test_multiset() {
    std::multiset<ItemKey> counter1 {{3.0, 10.0}, {5.0, 10.0}, {7.0, 10.0}};
    for (auto &item : counter1) {
       std::cout << "simple_test_multiset()::counter1: ("
                 << item.m_t << ", "
                 << item.m_f << ")\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::multiset<ItemKey> counter2 {{5.0, 10.0}, {3.0, 10.0}, {7.0, 10.0}};
    for (auto &item : counter2) {
       std::cout << "simple_test_multiset()::counter2: ("
                 << item.m_t << ", "
                 << item.m_f << ")\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "simple_test_multiset()::counter2.size() = "
              << counter2.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto &item : counter1) {
       std::cout << "simple_test_multiset()::counter2.count({"
                 << item.m_t << ", "
                 << item.m_f << "}) = "
                 << counter1.count(item) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs

```
simple_test_multiset()::counter1: (3, 10)
simple_test_multiset()::counter1: (5, 10)
simple_test_multiset()::counter1: (7, 10)

simple_test_multiset()::counter2: (5, 10)
simple_test_multiset()::counter2: (3, 10)
simple_test_multiset()::counter2: (7, 10)

simple_test_multiset()::counter2.count({3, 10}) = 2
simple_test_multiset()::counter2.count({5, 10}) = 3
simple_test_multiset()::counter2.count({7, 10}) = 2
simple_test_multiset()::counter2.size() = 3
```

Note that `count()` here returns the number of elements within the multiset that are considered equal to the `ItemKey` passed in.  This may be advantageous for situations where you want to ask "how many of my points are within my tolerance of a new point?"

Good luck!

Comment: While there are some useful information, since your comparison does not respect **strict weak ordering**, the behavior is undefined. Thus the answer is misleading. **It would help if you would read the documentation** instead of trying to understand the behavior by trying it. Any solution that involve an epsilon in comparison is UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: A multiset without epsilon would indeed works but the code that insert or search items then need to take appropriate action to take into account desired tolerance. At that point, it really depends on what one want to do with the data. In many case, it might be preferable to convert data to fixed point numbers or scaled integers so that you don't any floating point issues afterward.

Comment: **Strict weak ordering**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings

Comment: This ia brilliant answer! Thanks! And @Phil1970, thanks for sharing the article on strict weak ordering!

Comment: Yeah, you're right @Phil1970.  This doesn't follow a weak ordering, it fails on the last criterion (transitivity of incomparability).  Thanks for sharing that link.  Perhaps it would be best to create your own data structure to do what you want rather than depending on implementation details of undefined behavior from your compiler.  Maybe I'll edit my post later with a class that does what you want.  By the way, what exactly are you using this for?  Giving more details would help me make a class that does what you want.